# Revealing module implicity calling an internal function - is this a “smell”

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I'm trying to improve my javascript and have been using the revealing module pattern to good effect but I noticed that code in the module not in a function or the return is executed on creation have utilised this, such as:

```
var MyModule = function ($) {

    setUp();

    function setUp() {
        // execute code to be run when module created
    }

    function doStuff() {
    }

    return {
        doStuff: doStuff
    }
}
```

I can see this is creating a form of constructor for the function which relies on it being called by `var myModule = new MyModule(jQuery).`

Any feedback on the rights or wrongs of this appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, [you don't actually use the `new` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9304473/575527). It's valid to return something from a constructor, since constructors are functions as well. But when you use `new` to construct objects, it should return an instance of that constructor. In your case, you are returning an object, one that is not tied in any way to the constructor.

Here's the revealing module pattern and how it's used:

```
function createModule(name){

  //your private members, enclosed in createModule
  var privateVar = name;

  function privateFn(){
    console.log(privateVar);
  }

  //return a newly created object as the module
  return {
    //here, we have a function
    //since we live in the same scope as the privates, we can
    //also emulate getters and setters, classical OOP style
    getName : function(){
      privateFn();
    },
    setName : function(name){
      privateVar = name;
    }
  }
}

var newModule = createModule('mymodule');
newModule.getName(); //mymodule
newModule.setName('newname');
newModule.getName(); //newname
```

Now there are issues with this pattern, especially in usage:

**Pros**

- It emulates private members. This would be an easy start for developers coming from Classical OOP.
- Since the members are directly attached in the module, or at least only one scope above in the closure, they are fast.
- No prototype chains to worry about.

**Cons**

- Creating multiple modules mean creating multiple objects, each with it's own scope and functions. One module's `getName` function is not the same as another module's `getName()`. Although perfectly fine (And that's how classical OOP works, as far as I know), it's bad for the browser since it uses too much memory.
- You can't use `instanceof` to determine the modules since they *all* are instances of the `Object` object, and they are all object literals (`{}`) to begin with.

**Best use**

Single global modules, like libraries.

---

For spawning many modules, I suggest the native way of doing it, and would be creating instances using constructors and prototypes.

```
function Module(name){
  this.name = name;
}

createModule.prototype.getName = function(){
  console.log(this.name);
}

var newModule = new Module('mymodule');
newModule.getName(); //mymodule
newModule.name = 'newname';
newModule.getName(); //newname
```

It has its own issues as well:

**Pros**

- Smaller memory footprint. Anything attached to the constructor's prototype is shared, not duplicated, across instances. This means one instance's `getName` *is* the same function as another instance's `getName`. This is because of the prototype chain (think of it as inheritance chain), where instances "inherit" the same object.

**Cons**

- No private scope
- A long prototype chain is a performance penalty, especially if the method lives far up the chain.
- Overkill for a single module. It was meant to spawn multiple instances.

**Best Use**

Spawning multiple instances of the same kind, like elements in a game (units, enemies, bullets).

---

**What should you use**:

Depends. Libraries usually use a mix as well.

Take for instance, jQuery. The library itself is a module. They are revealed into the global scope using a modified revealing module pattern called "exports/expose pattern". Creation of instances of the jQuery object uses `new`, hidden behind the `jQuery` function.

```
(function(window,undefined){

  jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    //creating a new instance here
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
  }

  //...tons of library code here...

  //Expose, assign to window, basically creating the globals
  window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;

}(window));
```

When using jQuery as an object, it hosts exposed functions. This is when the module pattern is good at - singe direct fast global access.

```
$.ajax
$.noConflict
$.each
```

But when you use jQuery to wrap elements, wrap objects etc., it creates an instance of the constructor. This is where the constructor pattern is good at - creating multiple objects of the same kind.

```
//methods on these selectors are basically the same function, shared
// where in this case, each is shared
$('html').each(...
$('body').each(...
$('head').each(...

$('head').each === $('body').each //true
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply although your depiction of Revealing Module is actual closer to the module pattern.

Comment: Sorry joseph the commenting system wouldn't let me edit my original comment, what I was trying to say was: what you describe as the module pattern I've come across as Revealing Prototype.  Having now spent more time with js I can see that in my original question the fact that setup() function is called if you use new is a unintentional side effect so best not to do.